The concept of time

I exercise four hours after you learn something

I interpret this sentence for the following sentence.

I learn something, so than I exercise during four hours.

But, A book I refer to said this illustrative sentence means I learn something. I exercise four hours later.
Why This the sentence means?

The sentence doesn’t sound very natural. The relationship between its two halves—“I exercise” and “you learn something”—is unclear. One wonders why they are even appearing together in any sentence.

It's bot unnatural; and ambiguous. it's like the ambiguous employee recommendation: "You'll be lucky to get him to work for you."

"X four hours after Y" means you start doing X 4 hours after you finish doing Y. If you want to mean that you start X shortly after Y, and then continue doing it for 4 hours, you say "X for four hours after Y".

Why does the interpretation switch from "you learn" to "I learn"?

Which book!! Cite your sources If this sentence is in a book as an illustrative sentence.  I think you should get a better book. Illustrative sentences should make it easier to understand grammar lessons, not harder!

It is not a good sentence, but a very clumsy one. It's like showing us a video of a very drunk man stumbling down the street,  and asking us  "What kind of dance is he doing?"   I exercised for four hours, starting right after class ended.   or I began exercising four hours atter class ended.

You need to review the uses of the present simple tense.

I'd usually interpret this kind of ambiguity in terms of the context of the situation.  But in this case the context is so odd that this is impossible, and the sentence is simply ambiguous.
However "exercise four hours after" would normally mean that you start exercising after a gap of four hours. If you wanted to say a duration of four hours of exercise, you could say "I exercise for four hours after you learn something."
But as noted in the comments, there is no clear connection between you learning something and me exercising (at a gym?).  So if you said this as a learner, I'd just assume you'd made a mistake, and I would need to ask you to clarify what your ambiguous sentence means.
